# Opening and closing forge instance quickly creates updateTimeStamp errors

Tags: autodesk-forge

We're currently running our instance of forge within a react component that can be opened and closed, the container we use for forge is removed from the DOM when the model viewer is exited.

All is working well but when I've found a bug where if I open the forge instance and then quickly close it, or navigate to another route within our application, a series of errors are spooled in the console.
See screenshot below.

Our current clean up on dismount of the component is something like:

```
viewer.current!.finish();
viewer.current! = null;
window.Autodesk.Viewing.shutdown();
```

I've also tried adding:

```
viewer.current.uninitialize();
```

It seems to be only occurring if we don't give time to allow the full load to complete.

I'm wondering if there's a stage in our tear down that we're missing or if there's a recommended way to gracefully close the forgeviewer quite quickly after starting it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First [uninitialize](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#uninitialize) and then [shutdown](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/#shutdown)